# og:image tag not working in facebook

Tags: facebook, share

I have placed og:image meta tags in my jsp page inside the  section. However, when I post my page URL in Facebook, the content for the og:image is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the debugger?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
This will tell you what facebook is reading. (FYI, there's usually a delay, bug clicking [debug] will theoretically clear the cache)